# Validate angular form programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an angular directive used as attribute for validating the input.

Input looks like this (jade)

```
 input.form-control(type='text',  name='subjectinput', id='subjectinput',  subjectid-noprefix-validator='(subject.nosuffix==1)')
```

and validator looks like

```
.directive('subjectidNoprefixValidator', function () {     
    return {
        require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
        scope: {
            noprefixformat: '=subjectidNoprefixValidator'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

            scope.form = ctrls[0]; // so we can use form reference in displaying error messages
            var ngModel = ctrls[1];
            ngModel.$validators.subjectidnoprefix = function (value) { 
                var status = true;
                // removed some logic that sets status true or false
                // using   $scope.noprefixformat parameter
                return status;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

It works fine. However, sometimes in page actions an event happens that need validation to be re-triggered on the INPUT without touching it; some radio button alteration should re-trigger it and refresh validation status (as you see, my validator has a parameter).

I tried to achieve it by calling in page Controller

```
 $scope.subjCreationForm.subjectinput.$validate();
```

but it does not seem to work. What could be the case and is there another way to trigger validation of a field programmatically when it employs $validators?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412661/force-asyncvalidators-in-angularjs/30503030#30503030 my answer to similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the core of my problem, $apply has to be called manually that can be achieved as such:

```
           $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.subjCreationForm.subjectinput.$validate();
                });
```